# How to add custom applications in the status bar?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Talking about the Status bar of the windows phone 7.5.

It is allowed to add custom applications on the bar and be able to tap on them for being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't add icons to the status-bar, let alone assign them to applications.